# How to let an import library method access a file in android?

Tags: android, file, methods

One of the methods of an imported library requires a file's location like so:

```
libraryMethod(String file);
```

I have tried placing the file in different locations (Root, Assets folder ...) but I keep getting a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Try developing an Android app, by the use of proper Java language. Android Studio is an IDE.

Comment: Does your have read from disk permission? Are you sure the filename is correct? What is the file name string you're passing to this method

Comment: @MehmetKologlu The file's name is just 'model' (no extension) and I pass the file like: 
libraryMethod('model');
I've added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the AndroidManifest file but the file is located inside the project folder so I don't think that's the reason why I keep getting the error.

Comment: @statosdotcom Edited question.

Comment: Project folder? Like I'm your Android application folder? If it's not on the phones harddrive how do you expect an app to access it?

Comment: @MehmetKologlu The file doesn't need to change, it comes with the application. Is there any way I can include it in the project and let the library method access it ?

Comment: That's the whole thing, things in your project folder are not your application. Try reading about the assets folder. Things there do get ported with the app

Comment: @MehmetKologlu Still no luck, I've tried with: 
libraryMethod(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/model");
and I've also tried using:
Uri path = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/model");
libraryMethod(path.toString());

Comment: I just told you. For your application there is no file there. Your application doesn't include random files you put in your project folder

Comment: @MehmetKologlu The first test I did was placing the file in my phone's root folder and trying to access it using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). I've used the lather before to write to files (and place them in my phone's root directory which worked) but reading a file doesn't seem to work. The second try is using the Assets folder which you told me gets ported with the app ?